# How to add a 'Save' button on a new page which saves the file using iText7 on .NET

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext, asp.net-mvc-5, itext7

I want to a 'Save' button on a new page that saves the modifications made in my pdf. 

I am using this code:

- to add a new page `PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage();`
- to add a new button    `PdfButtonFormField button = PdfFormField.CreatePushButton(pdf, new Rectangle(479, 594, 45, 15), "save", "SAVE");`

My questions are:

- How do I add the button appear exactly on my new page?
- How do I make the button press save changes in the file?

I am using iText7 with ASP.NET MVC5.

References I used: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-9#379-submitform.java

Comment: If you are not using Adobe Acrobat, you will not be able to save modifications because Adobe prevents saving locally if you are using the free Adobe Reader. Other viewers (Preview, pdf.js, Chrome's PDF viewer,...) will just ignore the button.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, do you imply there is no way to save modifications?

Comment: An end user, opening a PDF in a PDF viewer can only locally save modificiations if the PDF viewer allows to do so. Foxit and Nitro viewers allow this; Adobe Acrobat also allows this. But the free Adobe Reader doesn't.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, does something like  button.SetAction(PdfAction.CreateSubmitForm("/PdfTemplates/SavePdf/" + pdfMetadata.id, null,PdfAction.SUBMIT_HTML_FORMAT | PdfAction.SUBMIT_COORDINATES)); work?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, please suggest how to save modifications locally using any of the above you mentioned.

Comment: I can not help you. People have tried to solve that problem before, and they solved it by posting the form to a local server, but then Adobe changed the End User License Agreement of Adobe Reader and made it legally impossible to do something that was technically possible. Please stop harassing me!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, that's very unfortunate. Thanks anyway. What do you mean by "Please stop harassing me!"? In which part I am harassing you?

Comment: Using @ with my name is not really what you want to do if you want an answer. You want to get an answer from the *community* (from anyone who might know the answer); you don't want to address your question to *one specific individual*. It is very annoying for me to get *personal requests* about PDF or iText. It makes me want to stop answering in general.

Comment: got it, I am new to stackoverflow, sorry:)